# ALTER TABLE table_name IMPORT TABLESPACE is giving me a "CFG file is missing and source table is found to have row versions" error. How do I fix this?

Tags: mysql

MySQL 8:

I replaced a .ibd file and then ran `ALTER TABLE table_name IMPORT TABLESPACE`

I get the following error even though my DB schema is identical to the original:

**Schema mismatch (CFG file is missing and source table is found to have row versions. CFG file is must to IMPORT tables with row versions.)**

What is a CFG file? How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I needed to run the following on the original DB to create the CFG file:

```
FLUSH TABLES table_name FOR EXPORT;
UNLOCK TABLES;
```

Comment: Yes. Did you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-table-import.html?